# Convert a list to a binary value in python

Tags: python, binary, ascii

I'm trying to program a Base64 coder in Python! I'm a student, and I have to do it in pure Python programing.

```
s='ab'
[ord(c) for c in s]
[97, 98]
```

Thats how Im converting strings to their ASCII values. So now I have to convert them to a concateneted binary value. So far I maneged to convert just one value, but when a try the whole list I get an error.

```
s=bin(int.from_bytes(s.encode(), 'big'))
0b110000101100010
```

That works. But when I try with the list:

```
s='ab'
s=[ord(c) for c in s]
bin(int.from_bytes(s.encode(), 'big'))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Tried my best to solve this and failed. Could you please help me in any way possible?

Comment: `s` is no longer a string. Only strings support the `encode` method. Remove the `s=[ord(c) for c in s]` step and you can access the `encode` attribute again.

Comment: You'll also need to include the `byteorder=` keyword argument to `int.from_bytes(...)`. You can use "big", "little", or `sys.byteorder` for the native endianess.